# How to stop a thread from opening a JDialog modal in Java Swing?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

So I have two modals. One modal is "Main dialog" where I'm opening "Tables dialog" through click on a button or through thread every X seconds.

Everything works fine if I'm not touching anything, thread do his job and automation works and opens "Tables dialog" every X seconds from last input time.

Problem comes when I click "Tables dialog", then automation of thread should stop from watching the "Tables dialog" and show only one table dialog. Instead of that, when I click "Tables dialog" it opens up and automation opens it one more time. I need to open it only once.

This is my trigger in Main modal.

```
   private Thread lockTableThread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (cashRegisterOpen) {
                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                    if (lockTable){
                        if (tryOpenCashRegisterDialog(currentTime)) {
                            if (isDialogOpenAtomic.get()) {
                                lastInputTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                                UpdateCurrentUser();
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (employeeClickTable){
                        dialog.dispose();
                    }
                    
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean tryOpenCashRegisterDialog(Long currentTime) {
            if (!isDialogOpenAtomic.getAndSet(true)) {
                try {
                    openCashRegisterDialog(currentTime);
                    return true;
                } finally {
                    isDialogOpenAtomic.set(false);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void openCashRegisterDialog(Long currentTime) {
            dialog = new ClientAppCashRegisterTablesDialog(null, true, currentTableId, startCashRegisterNumber, invoice.items.isEmpty(), true);
            if ((currentTime - lastInputTime) > lockTableTime * 2){
                  dialog.dispose();
                ClientAppLogger.GetInstance().LogMessage("Disposing a dialog");
               }
            
            dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                    // Reset the flag when the dialog is closed
                    isDialogOpenAtomic.set(false);
                    cashRegisterOpen = true;
                    lockTable = true;
                    employeeClickTable = false;
                }
            });
            
              dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                    if (employeeClickTable){
                        dialog.setVisible(false);
                        employeeClickTable = false;
                    }
                }
            });
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

In Tables Dialog I have:

```
if(!thisWindow.isFocused()){
     return false;
  }
```

I have tried numerous things but I cannot get it to work, from setModal(true) or dispose ...

Comment: Decouple it so that the thread isn't opening the window (as a side note, Swing is not thread safe)

Comment: How can I decouple it? And where?

Comment: Basically, the thread should be "generating" results which are "consumed" by the UI (or some other controller) - see [Producer/Consumer](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+producer+consumer); you then make use of some kind of [observer pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+observer+pattern) to notify interested parties that something has changed so they can the react to it. These (and a few other) concepts form the bases of the [model-view-controller](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+model+view+controller) concept

Comment: Yes, but thread looks every five seconds to open a dialog in "Main window". Because if employees did not touch anything, the "Second" dialog should show up. (thread continues to look but it should not trigger the "Second" dialog again. If employee comes on "Main" again, it should normally trigger "Second" dialog.

Comment: Swing is NOT thread safe, you shouldn't be interacting with the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread anyway - the whole idea of checking every 5 seconds sounds like a design smell to me, but, you could use a Swing `Timer` which would trigger the logic check and then, if required, would generate an appropriate event to some kind of controller, at which time it should just stop.  When needed again, the controller would start it again